# How to apply the Strangler Pattern with old Struts 1 application into Spring app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, struts-1

We currently have an old web application that's been developped under Struts 1.4.3 Framework. This application works fine on a production environment, 
but now we need to upgrade it to Spring. Instead of starting a new app as a greenfield project, we figured out that it could be a better idea for our client if we'd apply some transition techniques, such as the Strangler pattern. Then, we could bring some business value quickly to the client during the development process.

So here is our plan:

We will develop new screens one by one (Spring boot web app), and release those screens in production environment once they're ready.
I would like my main entry point to be into our new Spring boot application.
Then, I'd like to commute the requests of the client to whether new developed screen under spring boot controllers, or to old existing Struts 1 actions.
So for the user, the transition from a old to a new application would be 100% transparent

I found some solutions on Internet but none of them seems to give a clear way to proceed.
This article seems really appropriate to my need: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-sr2/index.html
But I'm having questions that the article does not answer.

1. Do Struts and Spring code base have to be within the same Java project in order to use the article's recipes?
2. The article stated above is 14 years old, so Spring libraries handling the integration of Struts appear to be deprecated. I can't find "org.springframework.web.struts" anymore in Spring framework 4.3.20. How to apply it now?

Thanks guys for your help.

Comment: There is no Struts 1.4.3. If you want to Springify your Struts app you'd use either an older version of Spring, or you'd set it up manually--the layer was pretty thin anyway.

Comment: Is there even a Struts 1.4 line? AFAIK 1.3.10 is the last Struts 1 version. Spring dropped support for it. So depending on what you want to achieve you might not need those Struts support classes (why would yo need them, as you already have a working Struts application?). If you really need, the sources are still available (for older versions) you can copy them an maintain the integration yourself. Depending the Struts to Spring integration, do you have session based state you need to share, are there other things to share. Al those might influence your decision on how to approach this.

Comment: I meant Struts 1.3.5, sorry for the confusion.
For now, I'm completely lost on how to proceed the integration of Struts actions into my spring project.

Comment: Would I need to move all the Struts code into my Spring project to make this integration possible?

In a perfect world, I would prefer to keep the Struts project distinct of the new Spring code that we're about to write.
So that's why I'm looking for a "dispatcher" that will handle the client requests and send them to the appropriate place (whether Spring controller or Struts action).